# I'm looking for advice on how and when to implement the dispose pattern. Are there any alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, dispose, destroy

How I dispose this iv instance?

```
 public IslemVekil GirisYap(KisiGirisModel _kgm)
    {
        IslemVekil iv = new IslemVekil();

        using (KisiVekil kv = new KisiVekil())
        {
            iv = IslemVekilGetir(kv);
        }

        return iv;
    }
```

**my workaround is:**

```
 private IslemVekil GirisYap(KisiGirisModel _kgm)
    {
        IslemVekil iv = new IslemVekil();

        try
        {
            iv = IslemVekilGetir(kv);
            return iv;
        }
        finally
        {
            iv.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for advice on how and when to implement the dispose pattern.
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: In the code that calls GirisYap add the return value of iv inside a using statement as you do here for the kv var

Comment: The title of the question is really unclear, can you rephrase it?

Comment: ı speak a little english, so sorry.. this is google translate :)

Comment: Why are you disposing it at all if you are returning it back to the caller?

Comment: what you recommend?

Answer (score -1):

You can do nested usings like this:

```
public IslemVekil GirisYap(KisiGirisModel _kgm)
{
    using (IslemVekil iv = new IslemVekil()) // first using
    using (KisiVekil kv = new KisiVekil()) // second using
    {
        iv = IslemVekilGetir(kv);
        return iv; // return here, because outside of this block 'iv' will be disposed
    }

    // return iv; - This is disposed and cannot be used
}
```

Anyway after you return iv, it won't work because it will be disposed again.

So instead of this you should add using statement in the calling code:

```
// ... calling code ... //
using (IslemVekil result = GirisYap(_kgm))
{
    // Do something with your 'iv' here
    result.DoSomethingFancy();
    ActUpon(result);
}
// Here your 'iv' is disposed
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not seem to be correct. You are assigning a value to your iv variable and then reassigning another value to it inside your using block.If IslemVekil is an IDisposable, in that case you will have memory leak right there inside your method. Consider this instead:

```
public IslemVekil GirisYap(KisiGirisModel _kgm)
    {
        IslemVekil iv;

        using (KisiVekil kv = new KisiVekil())
        {
            iv = IslemVekilGetir(kv);
        }

        return iv;
    }

public void Test(KisiGirisModel _kgm)
    {

        using (IslemVekil iv = GirisYap(_kgm))
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've given the example already. It works for both KisiVekil and KadinVekil :)

Comment: how to work? i really don't understand... 
how is the process sequence? IslemVekilGetir mehod how to do? :S how to return iv?